# Set jhipster app to target different backend host than localhost

Tags: jhipster

I have a jhipster app and deployed target/www to some webserver different where the backend is.. How to setup client app to target that server? I don't see any config regarding that.

Comment: There's no single place to do it, you must do it in all services. You could propose to create a constant and use it in all services and submit a pull request to the project.

Comment: I was wondering this was already taken care of as a Constant. Which branch should be used to create a pull request though? incase if I plan to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So currently your best solution is.

Search all the *.service.js files and replace the

var resourceUrl =  'api/projects/:id';

with your base url.

Better approach would be create a constant in app.constant.js